# How to user iter::product with parameter of length

Tags: c++, python-itertools, cartesian-product

In the code below, i want to get all products of length n, a parameter given to the function. Apparently, this product functions does not work with a parameter for the length. When I give an integer, the code does not complain.
I also want to iterate over all elements in the product and print them, but it says that it cannot print a tuple.

How can I solve this?

```
#include <../cppitertools-master/product.hpp>

vector<complex<double>> print_products(int n) {
    vector<complex<double>> solutions = {};
    vector<int> options = { 1, -1 };
 
    for (auto&& combination : iter::product<n>(options)) {
        for (auto&& c : combination) {
            cout << c << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The error I get when user the parameter n:

```
no instance of overloaded function "iter::product" matches the argument list, argument types are: (std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>)
```

The errors I get when trying to print the combinations when using 2 as a parameter:

```
this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found
```

Comment: You should link to libs used... https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/blob/master/product.hpp ?

Comment: `combination` should be something equivalent to `std::tuple<double, double>`, so a direct  `std::cout` won't work. it should be something like `std::apply([](auto... args){ ((std::cout << args << " "), ...); }, c);`.

Comment: `iter::product<n>` won't work with runtime value `n`, `template <std::size_t n> void print_products();` seems more adapted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iter::product<n>` requires `n` be a compile-time constant, which it is not.

This library has an open issue about implementing a version that takes a runtime count of repeats.

A tuple is not something that you can loop over with `for`. The return value of a runtime-count `product` can't be a tuple, so don't worry about the second error for your original case.

You have to index a tuple with compile time constants too.

```
for (auto&& combination : iter::product<2>(options)) {
    std::cout << get<0>(combination) << " " << get<1>(combination) << " " << std::endl;
}
```

If you template the count, you can use [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to hold a compile time sequence of numbers

```
template <typename T, size_t... Is>
void print_product(T&& combination, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    (std::cout << get<Is>(std::forward<T>(combination))), ...) << std::endl;
}

template <size_t N>
void print_products() {
    vector<int> options = { 1, -1 };
 
    for (auto&& combination : iter::product<N>(options)) {
        print_product(combination, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    }
}
```

Comment: [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) (C++17) might be use to avoid `std::index_sequence` usage: `std::apply([](auto&&... args){ ((std::cout << args << " "), ...) << std::endl; }, combination);`